# Citing sources that were used for creating a dataset in Chicago style

Tags: chicago-manual-of-style

I have created a dataset but I have collected data from other sources. How can I write that I used other sources? Do I have to put it into footnotes and bibliography as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chicago style doesn't directly address dataset citations, but the Webster University guide to [Chicago style](https://libguides.webster.edu/data/chicago) provides a guideline for citing datasets based on IASSIST recommendations. From this, it seems that yes, you should cite all your original source datasets following the template that they give:

> **Note** 19. Stephen Ansolabehere, Maxwell Palmer, and Amanda Lee, Precinct-Level Election Data, V1 (January 20, 2014), distributed by
> Harvard Election Data Archive, http://hdl.handle.net/1902.1/21919
> UNF:5:5C9UfGjdLy2ONVPtgr45qA==. Bibliographic
>
> **Entry** Ansolabehere, Stephen, Maxwell Palmer, and Amanda Lee. Precinct-Level Election Data. V1. January 20, 2014. Distributed by
> Harvard Election Data Archive. http://hdl.handle.net/1902.1/21919
> UNF:5:5C9UfGjdLy2ONVPtgr45qA==.